# How to kill a fired bullet sprite after certain amount of time in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, game-loop, timer, phaser

The bullet should be killed after it was shot from the player, and after a certain amount of time.

```
function create() {
    bullets = game.add.group();
    bullets.enableBody = true;
    bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
    game.physics.enable(bullets, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    timer = game.time.create(false);

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        bullet = bullets.create(0, 0, 'bullet');
        bullet.exists = false;
        bullet.visible = false;
        bullet.checkWorldBounds = true;
        bullet.events.onOutOfBounds.add(resetBullet, this);
    }
}

function update() {
    if (game.input.activePointer.isDown) {
        fire();
    }
}

function fire() {
    if (game.time.now > bulletTime) {
        bullet = bullets.getFirstExists(false);

        if (bullet) {
            bullet.reset(player.x, player.y);
            game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(bullet, 300);
            bulletTime = game.time.now + 150;
            timer.add(1000, resetBullet, this);
            timer.start();
        }
    }
}

function resetBullet(bullet) {
    bullet.kill();
}
```

As you can see I already tried adding a timer into the `fire` function which calls the `resetBullet` function after one second. But my game crashes one second after `fire()` was called:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kill' of undefined
```

Does anyone know how to achieve the kill of the sprite?

Comment: I am not familiar with phaser but I know in javascript you should use yield will need to have delay.i think you can fix your problem by this link http://goo.gl/U2imhI                                                                                         function shoot(){

if(nextShot>game.time.now){return;} // too early

/* make shot */

nextShot = game.time.now + 1000; // wait at least 1 second (1000ms) to next shot

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that objects can be killed with [`body.lifespan`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Component.LifeSpan.html)

Adding  the line `bullet.lifespan = 1000;` in my `fire()` function fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `bullet.destroy()` after a set amount of time as well.